# perl on php application on openshift

Tags: openshift

Hey Openshift dudes: is there any new facility to run a perl script (i.e. a Perl cartridge) inline with a PHP web application on openshift (high-availability mode)?

Or do I simply need to add a separate Perl application and just point it to the MYSQL database I've put in the PHP application. The Perl is just for ETL against that database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to run a command line Perl script, then you can just call it from PHP or CRON, all languages are available to all gears, the cartridge just says which one is your primary web language.  You can also use a .htaccess file to allow executing .pl files via http calls similar to this (but use perl instead of python) https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/ajax-failure-as-origin-not-allowed-in-access-control-allow-origin#comment-33585