# OpenShift PHP with .html Extension

Tags: php, apache, openshift, httpd.conf, addhandler

As we know, it is easy to get Apache to handle .html pages as PHP pages by adding the following line to http.conf:
**AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html**

How can this be done in OpenShift?

How can I edit http.conf in OpenShift?

Or is there another way?

Comment: Take a look here: https://forums.openshift.com/need-to-edit-httpdconf

Comment: Thanks Dimas but I've already searched extensively on the web and found this topic. But most importantly, it does NOT answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a .htaccess file?  Try the answer from this stackoverflow question, but use php instead of perl/python: [perl on php application on openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025044/perl-on-php-application-on-openshift)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, just add the following line to your .htaccess in any folders that it is required: AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html